# Using nested apply: apply for each row in each column

Tags: python, apply

I want to transform each row for all columns in a data frame.

So my dataset looks like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [100,100,100,100],
        'col2': [100,100,100,100],
        'col3': [100,100,100,100]
        })
df.index=pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=4, freq='D')
```

My function to-be applied is using the index and column name as input parameters and returns a transformation.
An example would be:

```
def apply_fct(row):
    
    # since row is a series, .name delivers rowname and .index the colname
    out=row[0] * row.name.day + row.index.values[0][-1]

    return(out)
```

So to apply this function for one column works fine using:

```
df['col2'].to_frame().apply(apply_fct,axis=1)
```

However, I need to apply it to all columns.

Since the number of columns and the names are variable, I need a more flexible approach.
I thought about a nested apply - but I am stuck.
Hope a loop is not the only option.

Answer (score 0):

You want to make sure your function puts out a series, and then you use apply for the whole dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [100,100,100,100],
    'col2': [100,100,100,100],
    'col3': [100,100,100,100]
    })
df.index=pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=4, freq='D')

def apply_fct(row):
out =(row * row.name.day).astype(str)+pd.Series(row.index,index=row.index)   
return(out)

df=df.apply(apply_fct,axis=1)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
            col1     col2     col3
2018-01-01  100col1  100col2  100col3
2018-01-02  200col1  200col2  200col3
2018-01-03  300col1  300col2  300col3
2018-01-04  400col1  400col2  400col3
```